# Please tell me why there is a "none" in my output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello guys I'm actually making a program in Python and it works fine but the problem is the output. there's always a "none" every value inside my list and I know it's not a big problem because it works but I can't help the fact that there's something about my system which is I'm not knowledgeable which is the displaying of "none" even if I don't want it too. I'm a beginner By the way. So thanks in advance.

```
class SchoolMember:

    def __init__(self,position,name,age):
        self.position = position
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

        print("Adding {} with {} of age as a {}".format(self.name, self.age, self.position))

    def tell(self):

        print("Position: {} | Name: {} | Age: {}".format(self.position, self.name,self.age))

class Teacher:

    def __init__(self,position,name,age,salary):

        SchoolMember.__init__(self,position,name,age)
        self.salary = salary

        print("Adding {} with an age of {} and a salary of {} as a {}".format(self.name,self.age,self.salary,self.position))

    def tell(self):

        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print("Salary: {}".format(self.salary))

class Student:

    def __init__(self,position,name,age,marks):

        SchoolMember.__init__(self,position,name,age)
        self.marks = marks

        print("Adding {} with an age of {} and a mark of {} as {}".format(self.name, self.age,self.marks,self.position))

    def tell(self):
        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print("Marks: {}".format(self.marks))



All = []

def addTeach():

    runningT = True

    while runningT:

        teachPos = 'Teacher'
        teachName = input('Enter the name of the Teacher: ')
        teachAge = input('Enter the age of the Teacher: ')
        teachSal = input('Enter the Salary of the Teacher: ')

        teachTemp = Teacher(teachPos, teachName, teachAge, teachSal)

        All.append(teachTemp)

        valY = input('Want to add more Teacher?(y/n): ')

        if valY.lower() == 'y':

            runningT = True

        elif valY.lower() == 'n':

            runningT = False


def addStud():

    runningS = True

    while runningS:

        studPos = 'Student'
        studName = input('Enter the name of the Student: ')
        studAge = input('Enter the age of the Student: ')
        studMarks = input('Enter the Marks of the Student: ')

        studTemp = Student(studPos, studName, studAge, studMarks)

        All.append(studTemp)

        valY = input('Want to add more Student?(y/n): ')

        if valY.lower() == 'y':

            runningS = True

        elif valY.lower() == 'n':

            runningS = False

def show():

    for all in All:

        print(all.tell())


running = True

while running:

    valX = input('Want to add a teacher or a student (s/t/v/n): ')

    if valX.lower() == 't':
        addTeach()

    elif valX.lower() == 's':
        addStud()
    elif valX.lower() == 'v':
        show()
    elif valX.lower() == 'n':
        running = False
```

The Output:

```
Want to add a teacher or a student (s/t/v/n): t
Enter the name of the Teacher: John Zahmir Olaer
Enter the age of the Teacher: 18
Enter the Salary of the Teacher: 90000
Adding John Zahmir Olaer with 18 of age as a Teacher
Adding John Zahmir Olaer with an age of 18 and a salary of 90000 as a Teacher
Want to add more Teacher?(y/n): y
Enter the name of the Teacher: John Bryan Labe
Enter the age of the Teacher: 17
Enter the Salary of the Teacher: 80000
Adding John Bryan Labe with 17 of age as a Teacher
Adding John Bryan Labe with an age of 17 and a salary of 80000 as a Teacher
Want to add more Teacher?(y/n): n
Want to add a teacher or a student (s/t/v/n): s
Enter the name of the Student: Delfin Razon
Enter the age of the Student: 24
Enter the Marks of the Student: 1.1
Adding Delfin Razon with 24 of age as a Student
Adding Delfin Razon with an age of 24 and a mark of 1.1 as Student
Want to add more Student?(y/n): y
Enter the name of the Student: Robin Bongo
Enter the age of the Student: 17
Enter the Marks of the Student: 2.1
Adding Robin Bongo with 17 of age as a Student
Adding Robin Bongo with an age of 17 and a mark of 2.1 as Student
Want to add more Student?(y/n): n
Want to add a teacher or a student (s/t/v/n): v
Position: Teacher | Name: John Zahmir Olaer | Age: 18
Salary: 90000
None
Position: Teacher | Name: John Bryan Labe | Age: 17
Salary: 80000
None
Position: Student | Name: Delfin Razon | Age: 24
Marks: 1.1
None
Position: Student | Name: Robin Bongo | Age: 17
Marks: 2.1
None
Want to add a teacher or a student (s/t/v/n): n

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I guess that's because Python returns `None` by default if nothing is returned by your function(s)

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why is the other functions, there's no none to it. Can I do something to now show the none part. just the "none" its pretty annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all.tell()` prints something and returns `None`; then `print(all.tell())` prints that `None`. You should either return text from `tell` and then print it from outside, or you should print in `tell` and then just have the plain call, not do both.

Comment: Thank you so much I've solved it through the knowledge you have shared. I'm very stupid, why did I print the all.tell at the show() method when its already been printed inside tell. thank you so much. How can I make some recommendation or something to give you  a big scorE?

Comment: Thank you, but gaming the system is neither required nor allowed. An upvote and a checkmark for answers that deserve it is all you are supposed to do.

Comment: Done. I'm sorry to ask such a silly question. I know that I should not questioned that but Curiosity Happens. No choice haha

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
print(all.tell())
```

Your classes `tell()` method prints to stdout and returns `None`, so this statement does prints `None` indeed.

As a side note: your code might seem to work but this is partly by accident - you are not using inheritance the right way. You want to make your `Teacher` and  `Student` classes inherit from `SchoolMember`, and (preferably) use `super()` to call on the parent class methods:

```
 class Teacher(SchoolMember):
    def __init__(self,position,name,age,salary):
        super().__init__(position,name,age)
        self.salary = salary

        # ...

    def tell(self):
        super().tell()        
        print("Salary: {}".format(self.salary))
```

etc.

Comment: @Alpha_Bords if you keep the `print(all.tell())` statement as is it will OF COURSE continue to print `None` - I thought this was obvious enough... The part about inheritance is totally unrelated.